# ggplot: Drawing separate y-lines when passing factor as argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create the following plot: The x-axis goes from 1 to 900 representing trial numbers. The y-axis shows three different lines with the moving average of reaction time. One line is shown for each difficulty level (Hard, Medium, Easy). Separate plots should be shown for each participant using facet_wrap.

Now this all works fine if I use ggplot's `geom_smooth()` function. Like this:

```
ggplot(cw_trials_f, aes(x=trial_number, y=as.numeric(correct), col=difficulty)) + 
    facet_wrap(~session_id) + 
    geom_smooth() + 
    ggtitle("Stroop Task")
```

The problem arises when I try to use **zoo** library's `rollmean` function. Here is what I tried:

```
ggplot(cw_trials_f, aes(x=trial_number, y=rollmean(as.numeric(correct)-1, 50, na.pad=T, align="right"), col=difficulty)) + 
    facet_wrap(~session_id) + 
    geom_line() + 
    ggtitle("Stroop Task")
```

It seems that this doesn't partition the data according to difficulty first and then apply the rollmean function, but the other way around. Thus only one line is shown but in all three colors. How can I have rollmean be applied to each category of trials (Easy, Medium, Hard) separately?

Here is some sample data:

```
  session_id test_number trial_number trial_duration  rule concordant switch correct reaction_time difficulty
1   11674020           1            1           1872  word concordant    yes     yes          1357       Easy
2   11674020           1            2           2839  word discordant     no     yes          2324     Medium
3   11674020           1            3           1525 color discordant    yes      no          1025       Hard
4   11674020           1            4           1544 color discordant     no      no          1044     Medium
5   11674020           1            5           1451  word concordant    yes     yes           952       Easy
6   11674020           1            6           1252 color concordant    yes     yes           746       Easy
```

Comment: There might be a way to get this to work within ggplot by moving the aesthetic mappings between layers, but really you simply shouldn't be calling `rollmean` from inside `aes`. Just use `ddply` to calculate the rolling mean as a new variable first, and then do your plotting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ended up doing this and posted the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up following @joran's suggestion (thanks) from the comment above and did the following:

```
cw_trials_f <- ddply(cw_trials_f, .(session_id, difficulty), .fun = function(X) transform(X, movrt = rollmean(X$reaction_time, 50, na.pad=T, align="right"), movacc = rollmean(as.numeric(X$correct)-1, 50, na.pad=T, align="right")))
```

This adds two additional columns to the data.frame with the moving averages of accuracy and reaction time.

Then this works fine to plot them:

```
ggplot(cw_trials_f, aes(x=trial_number, y=movacc, col=difficulty)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~session_id) + ggtitle("Stroop Task")
```

There is one (minor) disadvantage to this compared to what I originally wanted to do: It makes it a bit tedious and slow to try out different lengths for the moving average function.